# How to set default fonts to custom families defined with babel?

Tags: fonts, babel

I have custom font files which I load with `\babelfont` with custom settings:

```latex
\babelfont{assistant}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    Path = ./fonts/assistant/,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.3}
]{Assistant}
```

I want to use this font with these settings as the main `rm` font for my language Hebrew. I could copy-paste the definition:

```
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    Path = ./fonts/assistant/,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.3}
]{Assistant}
```

But it doesn't feel right. I want to have the custom font defined regardless of the main font so I can always use `\assistantfamily` and `\assistanttext` in case I decide to use a different `rm` font in the future. However, for now I want to use this font as the main font.
I tried things like `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{david}` and `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{\davidfamily}`, but it didn't work. How can I use a custom family defined with `\babelfont` as the main font?

Here's a minimal example of the code I use:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% Font setup
\babelfont{assistant}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    Path = ./fonts/assistant/,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.3}
]{Assistant}

% How can I use the previously defined `assistant` family instead of copy-pasting its settings?
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    Path = ./fonts/assistant/,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.3}
]{Assistant}

\begin{document}
שלום לכולם
\[ E = mc^2 \]
\end{document}
```

Here's the file structure:

[image]

Comment: Neither `babel` nor, afaik, `fontspec` provide such a feature. Fonts are very complex structures that cannot be just reassigned. You can save your settings in a macro (let’s call it `\assistantfeats`) and then pass it as the second optional argument (like `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[\assistantfeats]{Assistant}`).

Comment: you could probably setup a assistent.fontspec file with your settings and then use this to load the font, see the fontspec documentation.